# How to get the key of every single object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database contains a json data and I append it in cardViews, I want to get the key of the cardView when it clicked but instead it returns an array of the all objects in the database 
this is my index.js:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Stories");
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
  var title = snap.child("Story Title").val();
  var content = snap.child("Story Content").val();
  $("#stories").append("<div  id=\"cold\" class=\"col s8 m6\"><div 
    class=\"card\"><div class=\"card-image\"><img 
    src=\"https://www.joshmorony.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/firebase.png\">
    <a  class=\"btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red\"><i   
    class=\"material-icons\">info</i></a></div><div class=\"card-content\"><p 
    onclick=\"viewKey()\">" + title + "</p></div></div></div>");
  });

  function viewKey() {
    firebase.database().ref('/Stories/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      var storiesArray = snapshot.val();
      var keys = Object.keys(storiesArray);
      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var currentStory = storiesArray[keys[i]];
       console.log(currentStory);
      }

    });
  }
```

the object array :
["-Ko8JpEjsdN2KGBdIG3f", "-Ko8JtdcEBICVZqIXLdO", "-Ko8TvZuu0Wh_XDGa1YW","-KoBR0NmVmerjomE63-V", "-KoBSOybd5ymvOwz0Ip6"]

Comment: try console.log(keys[i]) in for loop

Comment: also still returns all objects keys array

Comment: Can you post your storiesArray object

Comment: Your code would give an error at `console.log(currentStory)` because `currentStory` is only defined inside the `for` loop

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be the answer:  snapshots have a key.

Since you are using child_added, each child is read in one at a time, so each child snap.key will give you the key to that child snapshot. In other words, the code within the closure after the child_added line will run once for each child node within the Stories node.

If you were to use value instead, that would read in ALL of the data in the Stories node in one 'big' snapshot (one parent with multiple children). So it would look like

```
Stories
  story_0
    story_info: "ads"
  story_1
    story_info: "assad"
```

In that case, you would need to iterate over the Stories snapshot to get each child (story_0, story_1 etc). Each child would be it's own snapshot with it's own snapshot.key.

See [Work with Lists of Data on the Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)

This code will output the key for each story when using child_added:

```
var storiesRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Stories");
storiesRef.on('child_added', function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.key);
});
```

If you want to get all of the Stories at one time using value, this will read in the Stories node and iterate over the child nodes, outputting each key

```
storiesRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    console.log(childSnapshot.key);
  });
});
```

Note the child_added function above will get each child and continue to listen for child_added events whereas the value function above will execute once and not listen for future events.